# The domain of the derivative of an inverse function

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

Let $N(x) = f^{-1}(x)$, and $f(1) = 3$

Is $N'(3) =\frac{1}{f'(3)}$ or $\frac{1}{f'(1)}$?

Answer (score 1):

In general,
\begin{align}
\left(f^{-1}\right)'(x) &= \dfrac{1}{f'\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)}.
\end{align}
I leave it to you to plug in everything carefully.

Comment: ok so it's $f^{-1}(3)$, $f'(1)$?

Comment: @HengWei yes that's right.

Comment: ok thanks a lot